# App crashes when passing data from RecyclerView in Fragment to Activity with Glide

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-glide

Hello I am trying to pass data from my RecyclerView in Fragment, to my activity. But the app crashes. The code works when i try to open another activity so im guessing the error is in my Gallery.java activity.
I tried putting .asBitMap where it says Glide in Gallery.java Activit, but it is marked as an error
Here is my Gallery.java

```
package co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo;

import android.nfc.Tag;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

public class Gallery extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);
        getIncomingIntent();
    }
    private void getIncomingIntent(){
       if(getIntent().hasExtra("image_url")){
           String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
           String imageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_name");
           setImage(imageUrl,imageName);
        }
    }
    private void setImage(String imageUrl, String imageName){
        TextView name= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.idInfo);
        ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.idImagen);
        Glide.with(this)


                .load(imageUrl)
                .into(image);


    }
}
```

Here is my adapter class

```
package co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.adapters;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.Gallery;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.R;
import co.quindio.sena.navigationdrawerejemplo.clases.PersonajeVo;
import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

/**
 * Created by CHENAO on 13/07/2017.
 */

public class PersonajesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PersonajesAdapter.PersonajeViewHolder>{

    ArrayList<PersonajeVo> listaPersonaje;
    private Context mContext;

    public PersonajesAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<PersonajeVo> listaPersonaje) {
        this.listaPersonaje=listaPersonaje;
        this.mContext=context;
        ArrayList<String> mImages = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String>mImageNames = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public PersonajeViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);
        return new PersonajeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonajeViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.txtNombre.setText(listaPersonaje.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.txtInformacion.setText(listaPersonaje.get(position).getInfo());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Gallery.class);


                intent.putExtra("image_url", (Parcelable) listaPersonaje.get(position));
                intent.putExtra("image_name", (Parcelable) listaPersonaje.get(position));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaPersonaje.size();
    }

    public class PersonajeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtNombre,txtInformacion;
        ImageView foto;

        public PersonajeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            txtNombre= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNombre);
            txtInformacion= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idInfo);
            foto= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *`App crashes`* Where is your crash report, Please share that crash log with question

Comment: How are people supposed to help you when you don't have stacktraces to show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is:

you send a Parcelable:

```
intent.putExtra("image_url", (Parcelable) listaPersonaje.get(position));
                intent.putExtra("image_name", (Parcelable) listaPersonaje.get(position));
```

but get it as String

```
String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
           String imageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_name");
```

so please using  `getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image_url")` and  `getIntent().getParcelableExtra("image_name")`

or send a String

```
intent.putExtra("image_url", listaPersonaje.get(position).getImageUrl());
                intent.putExtra("image_name",listaPersonaje.get(position).getImageName());
```

assume `listaPersonaje` item have `getImageName()` and `getImageUrl()` method that get `"image_url"` and `"image_name"` value

**UPDATE 1** If you want send a drawable, first, convert it to byte array

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.your_resource);     
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); 
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

and pass it via intent extras, 
send:

```
intent.putExtra("image_url", b);
```

and receiver:

```
byte[] b = getIntent().getByteArray("image_url");
```

finally, using it for image view

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
```

**UPDATE 2** In case we have a drawble, we need to convert it to bitmap

```
public static Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
        if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() != null) {
            return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
        }
    }

    if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0) {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888); // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
    } else {
        bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    drawable.draw(canvas);
    return bitmap;
}
```

**UPDATE 3**, finally, using both of 2 way above, we have a way to resolve your issue when pass a drawable via intent

```
   Drawable drawable = listaPersonaje.get(position).getImageUrl()
        // convert drawable to byte array
        Bitmap bitmap = drawableToBitmap(drawable);
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
        byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
        // send it
        intent.putExtra("image_url", b);
        <!----------------------------------------------->
        // receiver
        byte[] b = getIntent().getByteArray("image_url");
        // and using glide to show it 
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(b)
                .asBitmap()
                .into(imageview);
```

Comment: Worked for text, but not for the image. How do I get the image in the new Activity??

Comment: Its a drawable, im also trying to pass a drawable, aswell as the text

Comment: Let me remind you that the imageview is part of a recyclerview, So i cant call the name of a specific drawable. It has to work depending  on which item I click on my RecyclerView

Comment: getResources is supposed to get the image? so I have to change that getter to the name of the getter I created previously

Comment: Oh, my mistake, if `listaPersonaje.get(position).getImageUrl())` return a drawble, we need to convert it to bitmap, then covert bitmap to byte array, I updated my answer, please check again

Comment: ok I did that, but what do I do after that? do I still need what you put in Update 1?? in the code I get errors on getResources

Comment: I have `update 3` that base on your issue, please check it

Comment: I have another issue, Am I uppsed to create another method called getImageURL?

Comment: The drawable is an ImageView located in the drawable folder

Comment: And also i think supposed to be getByteArrayExtra not getByteArray

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing only image_url and image_name then you have no need to pass as Parcelable.you just pass the only string in intent.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Gallery.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_url",listaPersonaje.get(position));
                intent.putExtra("image_name", listaPersonaje.get(position));
                mContext.startActivity(intent);

And fetch data in Gallery Activity


String imageUrl = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_url");
           String imageName = getIntent().getStringExtra("image_name");


I hope its help you.
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add some more information here in addition to the @gianhtran s answer.

In bindviewholder method, you will get the PersonajeVo object by listaPersonaje.get(position).

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonajeViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        final PersonajeVo personajeVo = listaPersonaje.get(position);
        holder.txtNombre.setText(personajeVo.getNombre());
        holder.txtInformacion.setText(personajeVo.getInfo());
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Gallery.class);
                intent.putExtra("image_url", personajeVo.getImageUrl());
                intent.putExtra("image_name", personajeVo.getImageName());
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
```

Secondly, if you want all of the details from PersonajeVo object, then  you can put it this way,

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("personaje_obj",personajeVo); //make sure personjeVo model class is parcelable or cast it as (Parcelable)personajeVo
    mContext.startActivity(intent);)
```

and getting it back in another activity as follows,

```
Intent mIntent = getIntent();
if(mIntent!=null && mIntent.hasExtra("personaje_obj"))
{
PersonajeVo personajeVo = mIntent.getParcelableExtra("personaje_obj");
}
```

Comment: What is personajeVo? And image name is not the files name, but a textView.

Comment: @LuisRivera  PersonajeVo is what I think was a model class holding the fields String imageName, imageUrl with getters and setters for both and it should implement Parcelable. ' personajeVo' is object of that class. Eventually, the Arraylist should be ArrayList<PersonajeVo> listaPersonaje.

Answer (score 0):

Actually no need to intent inside onBindViewHolder. Do it in this way

```
 public class PersonajeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView txtNombre,txtInformacion;
    ImageView foto;
    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        int get = AdatperPosition();
   if(pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
   Item clickDataItem = listaPersonaje.get(position); 
   Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Gallery.class);
   intent.putExtra("image_url", listaPersonaje.get(position));
   intent.putExtra("image_name",  listaPersonaje.get(position));
   mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```